# custom class css autocomplete

Tags: css

How can I autocomplete in a html file in a tag using the "class=" attribute, the css class definition writted in my css file ?

Say that I have  test.html with style.css.  In style.css I defined

```
.banner-heading {..}
.banner-sub-heading {..}
```

When in test.html I write :

```
<p class="ba">
```

I would lile a liste of class beginning with "ba" including my user-defined classes "banner-..".
Hope to be clear enough.

And also maybe on the contreverse if I write in

```
<p class="banner-heading">
```

To get a list in my style css file when  I type :

```
.ban
```

Thank